# Can't reach Vnet using VPN gateway while peering is on

Tags: azure, networking, vnet, azure-vpn

[image]

Hello ,
I have 2 Vnets, a Vnet containing Vms (Private Vnet)
a Vnet containing an Aks Cluster (Private but the pod I want to use is public (exposed using LB))
to Connect to Vnet1 from my local I'm using a Vpn Gateway but when I added I Network peering betweeen Vnet1 & Vnet2 , Suddenly I can't reach my private vms even when im connected to the vpn
although the peering between Vnet1 & vnet2 Is working just fine
I can reach my private vms from aks pods
here is my vnets/subnets

GatewaySubnet 172.17.1.0/24

default 172.17.0.0/24

my vpn config :

- point to site
- Address pool 10.0.0.0/16
- Tunnel type IKEv2 and OpenVPN(SSL)
- Active-active mode : disabled
- Gateway Private IPs : disabled
- VPN type : Route Based

and here is my peering configuration :

[image]

[image]

I don't know what is causing this
I hope somebody can guide me to the right direction

Comment: Use none in both peering for **Virtual network gateway or Router Sever** that might solve your problem.

Comment: I already tested it and it didn't work

Comment: Could you please confirm if you are unable to reach the databases Vnet or AKS Vnet from VPN client?

Comment: yes I can't reach any resource in the Vnet Databases & Aks  using the Vpn Client

Comment: Can you Tell us what is vnet aks adresse space ?

Comment: yes it's 10.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 0):

the "aks" vnet has an address space of "10.0.0.0/8" that overlaps with the VPN's Point to Site VPN client address pool.
Changing the adress pool of your p2s config will solve your problem